# simplexml_load_file omitting 00 from xml to csv

Tags: php, xml, csv, simplexml

I have an XML

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StockValues>
  <Product>
    <Product_Code>00380</Product_Code>
    <Available_Stock>200</Available_Stock>
    <Due_Date>2013-10-13</Due_Date>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_Code>00429</Product_Code>
    <Available_Stock>200</Available_Stock>
    <Due_Date>2013-11-14</Due_Date>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_Code>00495</Product_Code>
    <Available_Stock>200</Available_Stock>
    <Due_Date>N/A</Due_Date>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_Code>0122</Product_Code>
    <Available_Stock>200</Available_Stock>
    <Due_Date>N/A</Due_Date>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_Code>0190</Product_Code>
    <Available_Stock>200</Available_Stock>
    <Due_Date>2013-10-16</Due_Date>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_Code>052A</Product_Code>
    <Available_Stock>200</Available_Stock>
    <Due_Date>N/A</Due_Date>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_Code>052B</Product_Code>
    <Available_Stock>200</Available_Stock>
    <Due_Date>2013-10-09</Due_Date>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_Code>052BK</Product_Code>
    <Available_Stock>200</Available_Stock>
    <Due_Date>2013-09-28</Due_Date>
  </Product>
```

I am using simplexml_load_file to convert to a CSV. It works great but 2 problems. Firstly my product codes starting with 00 lose the 00 in generating CSV. Therefore I somehow need to keep this is as a text field.

Secondly, I would like to put column headings in here also.

This is the code I have adapted so far:

```
<?php

$filename='test.csv';   

       if (! file_exists($filename))
            {
             echo "There's no test file";
             }
        else
             {
                echo "There's 1a test file !";
                unlink($filename);
                }

        echo '<br />';

        if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_file('1feed2.xml') )
    {
            echo 'unable to load XML file';
            }
        else
            {

            foreach( $xml as $product_record )
                {
                    $prodarray = "\"$product_record->Product_Code\"".","."$product_record->Available_Stock".",END\n";
                    echo $prodarray;
                    //echo '<br />';
                    file_put_contents($filename,$prodarray,FILE_APPEND);

                    echo "line written <br />";


                }
            }


                    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
                    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
                    fclose($handle);
                    print $contents;

?>
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

It currently generates a CSV which is great but just missing the above bits.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you need to add `01`, `02` and `03` values in your csv file.

While creating your csv, if you just pass 01,02,03 to the csv file the 0 value won't be displayed when you open the csv file.

To solve this problem just append the file like '01,'02,'03. And the zeros will be displayed when you open the file.

Just remember to add `'` character before the column value.

Edit

You haven't mentioned if the column names are fixed or whether it depends on your xml.

I'll try to answer this on the assumption that your column names don't change.

Create a function which appends your data to a csv file. (Although this is not necessary.)

```
function addRowToCsv($data, $filename){
    file_put_contents($filename,$data,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

In order to add the column names just call the function before the foreach loop.

`addRowToCsv("Product Code, Available Stock, Status\n");`

See the below updated code.

```
<?php

    $filename='test.csv'; 

    if (! file_exists($filename))
    {
        echo "There's no test file";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There's 1a test file !";
        unlink($filename);
    }

    echo '<br />';

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('1feed2.xml');

    //avoid unnecessary else and elseif statments.
    if(!$xml){
        echo 'unable to load XML file';
        exit;
    }

    //adding column names
    addRowToCsv("Product Code, Available Stock, Status\n");

    foreach($xml as $product_record){
        $product_code = (int) $product_record->Product_Code;
        $available_stock = (int) $product_record->Available_Stock;

        //Add ' character before the column value
        $csv_line = "'$product_code,'$available_stock,END\n";
        addRowToCsv($csv_line);
    }

    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");

    if($handle){
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);
        print $contents;
    }

    function addRowToCsv($data, $filename){
        file_put_contents($filename,$data,FILE_APPEND);
    }
?>
```

Comment: But the data feed is outside of my control. So how would the file code look?

Comment: Also do you know how I can add column headings? Thank you